# where should I put build dependencies in a node web app

Tags: node.js, frontend

we use nodejs a lot in production, it's perfect for web because we use same language for frontend and backend, but when we put both frontend and backend in one source root, it has problems. where should I put build dependencies? should I put dependencies like webpack, babel in dependencies or in devdependencies? I found both option is not good. I hope **dep like these are not packaged into my final dist package**. but I have to install that in order to build static assets in my ci pipeline.

my current workaround is to **install twice**. I put these dependencies in devdependencies, and dep for backend in dependencies, and the first installation is to install all deps to build static assets, after that, I remove the node_modules, and install again just for dependencies.

I don't like this workaround either, it increase build time a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the dependencies the app need to run into the "dependencies" section and build/development based dependencies in "devDependencies".

The trick is to run `npm install --production` which only installs the production dependencies i.e. packages under "dependencies".

`npm install` does install both the production dependencies and the devdependencies, so there is no need for duplication or installing twice.

Comment: of cause I know the difference between devDependency and dependency, please read the question carefully, I need to first build static assets, so I have to install all dependencies, after that, how can I remove those deps I don't need for backend?